# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (103:19) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, compiler-errors, babel-loader

I earlier installed " socket.io-client " and it gave me some vulnerabilities so I ran `npm audit fix --force`  in my command line.
After that I tried to run my project and it is giving me this error

```
./src/Pages/Groups Page/groupsPage.js 103:19
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (103:19)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       columnNumber: 11
|     }
>   })), profileData?.groupSupporter?.groupName === "" && /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("button", {
|     onClick: handleBecomeSupporterClick,
|     className: "brizzle_groupsPage_groupShowContainer_supporterButton",
```

Here is the given line with the error. I tried to comment it but it just shows another line.

```
//this is a component i am trying to render and the line 103 is the last line of the component 
//where the 19th column does not even exist
       <GroupEdit
          setConfigure={setConfigure}
          editFlag={editFlag}
          setEditFlag={setEditFlag}
        />
```

And
These are my package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.10.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.2",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.6.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

What should I do. And what does this error even mean.
My current loader for css is the `post-css-loader`